# Azure function dotnet-isolated v4

Tags: azure-functions, .net-6.0, dotnet-isolated

I have recently started my C# journey so bare with me...

so my issue is that after installing azure-functions-core-toolsv4 (mac using brew) I was finally able to see why Rider (which use the same as a plugin) just exited with error (Process finished with exit code 137.).

I was trying to fix another issue we get after switching to dotnet-isolated - namely:

`Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The gRPC channel URI 'http://:0' could not be parsed.`

After a ton of googling I found that this apparently occurs if I try to run my function locally using the "normal" run (dotnet run...) - that is invoked if I just hit run on my Program.cs Main. Instead I should go for "func host start ..." provided via the Azure Functions Core Tools.

So my error is:
`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: WorkerConfig for runtime: dotnet-isolated not found. Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')`

So my problem is that no matter what I do I get the same two kinds of errors after switching to `dotnet-isolated`, when I try to run my startup my functions on my developer laptop (both on my mac and on my windows laptop) (it runs fine on Azure portal).

Looking at the second error it really puzzles me why I see the "WebJobs" namespace - as far as I have understood part of the new dotnet-isolated is to switch completely away from the WebJobs stuff...

Comment: Is your storage connection string value for `AzureWebJobsStorage` correct?

Comment: My current settings looks like this - used to work before installing Azure Functions Core Tools v4:
`"Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",`

Comment: Does changing the value to a real azure storage connection string work?

Comment: In my host.json I had the following included:

`"extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
    },`

This is NOT a good idea - after removing it my functions started up without any issues.
(it does not matter which version of the extensions you include - it just jams everything when you run dotnet-isolated !! )

Comment: @Shyju - nope - this was actually not the issue. Apparently it was "a thing" I had picked up another recommendation.... - se above.

Comment: Yea, isolated functions should not use extension bundles in host.json.

Comment: For me, Azure tables caused this issue, and after I removed it everything worked fine. try to look in .csproj file.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the extensionBundle section in my host.json fixed the problem.

After removing this my `func start --csharp` works fine from commandline, Rider and Visual Studio.